# Autocompletado para buscador comportamiento extraño

Tags: laravel, script, autocompletar

Estoy usando un **Script** de autocompletado para el buscador me funciona correctamente pero tengo un problema que cuando intento usar cualquier acceso directo con el símbolo # me lo copia al input del buscador, por ejemplo intento acceder a un div con  `<a href="#div1"><a>` y me lo copia al input..

**Script**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#nombre').keyup(function(){
          var query = $(this).val();
          if(query != '')
          {
           var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
           $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('autocomplete.fetch') }}",
            method:"POST",
            data:{query:query, _token:_token},
            success:function(data){
             $('#List').fadeIn();
                      $('#List').html(data);
            } }); } });
      $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
          $('#nombre').val($(this).text());
          $('#List').fadeOut();
      });

  });
  </script>
```

**Controller** "creo que el problema esta en el Script pero comparto el Controller por si fuera necesario"

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class AutocompleteController extends Controller
{

    function index()
    {
     return view('autocomplete');
    }

    function fetch(Request $request)
    {
     if($request->get('query'))
     {
      $query = $request->get('query');
      $data = DB::table('products')
        ->where('nombreyape', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
        ->get();
      $output = '<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display:block; position:absolute">';
      foreach($data as $row)
      {
       $output .= '
       <li><a href="#">'.$row->nombreyape.'</a></li>
       ';
      }
      $output .= '</ul>';
      echo $output;
     }
    }

}
```

**Explicación mas extensa de mi fallo**

el problema es que si intento llamar a cualquier div usando la # como por ejemplo `<a href="#div1"><a>`o `<a href="#loquequieras"><a>` da igual que no  exista el div pero al hacer clic en el enlace el texto me lo copia al buscador por ejemplo de `<a href="#div1"><a>` me copia al buscador **div1**

Comment: Cuando intentas acceder? no entiendo a que te refieres, adicional no entiendo arriba mencionas div1 pero en tu script no haces mención, supongo que es un ejemplo, pero deberías ser mas especifico para así poder entender el problema, saludos.

Comment: Parece que el error se produce aquí ` $(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
          $('#nombre').val($(this).text());
          $('#List').fadeOut();
      });`
pero no consigo solucionarlo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado cambie esto

```
$(document).on('click', 'li', function(){
          $('#nombre').val($(this).text());
```

Por esto

```
$(document).on('click', '.datalist', function(){
          $('#nombre').val($(this).text());
```

y esto

```
<li><a href="#">'.$row->nombreyape.'</a></li>
```

por esto

```
<li class="datalist"><a href="#">'.$row->nombreyape.'</a></li>
```